# Issue with adding a route to a sub-network card

Tags: iproute

I'm trying to add any route to a sub-network card eth0:1. When I'm running "ip route list" then this command prints the saved rule for eth0 not for eth0:1. Why ? How to solve that?

```
ip route add 192.168.1.1 dev eth0:1

ip route list 
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 scope link
```

Comment: On Linux `eth0:1` is not an interface, it's an IPv4 address with a label, for compatibility with the deprecated `ifconfig` command (which from a compat API sees it as an interface, because that's the only way to add a 2nd IPv4 address when using ifconfig: an obsolete way). Whenever you use `eth0:1` it will be replaced by `eth0` or be treated as an error or something that never matches depending on where it's used. Explain your problem rather than your attempt at solving it ( https://xyproblem.info/ ).

Comment: I have opened a new request - https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/why-dockers-send-https-requests-from-one-ip-address-if-each-of-them-has-dedicate .  I thought I can solve this problem by using ip route with src address.